# Getting to know SQL via the "short questions/simple answers style of learning"

Tags: learning

Looking for a incremental SQL course that would likely be similar to the this [Ruby Koan course](http://koans.heroku.com/); which is in fact inspired by the book, "[The Little Lisper](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0023397632)", which uses a short questions/simple answers style of learning.

Basically the format is short questions are within a well defined context, with a simple answer, that incrementally building and leveraging the student's knowledge within the subject matter, while keeping the to the short questions/simple answers style of learning.

Also, I just wanted to note that I know there are a number of ways to learn SQL, but I'm looking for an existing implementation of this way. This style provides a fixed-path with stepping stones, and if you do not finish a set of questions, you're not allowed to go on, and even if you were able to find a way to cheat this, it would just make things harder, not easier; meaning it's not just free-form learning with information present small packets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at:

http://sqlzoo.net/

This seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly question and answer type, but this is the best SQL tutorial I have seen so far: http://sol.gfxile.net/galaxql.html

Comment: +1 @yogirk:  I tried it out, and agree it's nice. That said, within less than 5-mins of installing it I ran across one bug; the load file function referenced a file that does not exist. Also, on the first page of the tutorial it asks you to figure out how many seconds are in a day, but never says at any point to the user how to do it, or infer it from other examples; the answer being "SELECT 24*60*60". So, basically after those issues I stopped trying it, might try it more later, but also agree it not the format I describe; which leads to the student internalizing that material I believe.